# how to make some logic in next js 13 when user updating a page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

how to make some logic in next js 13 when updating a page and it doesn’t matter at which url the page was updated.
In react it worked when I wrote some logic in App.tsx, it worked wherever the user refreshed the page. please help

Comment: You can use the [layout.tsx](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#layouts) file, it only executed logic on hard navigation or a [template.tsx](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/template), it will execute logic on each page change.

Comment: exactly, I completely forgot. Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here a more complete answer. When working with Next.js 14 you can either use the [template.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/template) or [layout.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#layouts) convention. Here are the key differences between the two:

##### layout.js

A layout file, usually a server component has the following traits: On navigation, layouts preserve state, remain interactive, and do not re-render. Layouts can also be [nested](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#nesting-layouts). Every app router instance needs to have a [at least one](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups#creating-multiple-root-layouts) root layout containing the `<head />` `<html />` and `<body />` tags.

```
interface Props extends React.PropsWithChildren {}

// app/layout.tsx
export default function RootLayout({ children }: Props): JSX.Element {
  // this will only log on hard navigation
  console.log("Hello RootLayout!");
  return (
    <html>
      <head />
      {/* the children are pages, layouts, templates etc further down the tree */}
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

##### template.js

A template file is similar to a layout in that it wraps each child layout or page. Unlike layouts that persist across routes and maintain state, templates create a new instance for each of their children on navigation. When a user navigates between routes that share a template, a new instance of the component is mounted and state is **not** preserved.

```
"use client";

import { useEffect } from "react";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

interface Props extends React.PropsWithChildren {}

// app/template.tsx
export default function MyTemplate({ children }: Props): JSX.Element {
  const pathname = usePathname();
 
  // will output the pathname on soft and hard navigation for each page
  useEffect(() => console.log("pathname:", pathname), [pathname]);

  // the children are pages and child layouts further down the tree
  return <>{children}</>;
}
```